# Skipping when value is Null in ArcMap dynamic label expression?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, python-parser

I have a table of contents with multiple owner agencies that may or may not have an acreage value in the field and am trying to get a dynamic label expression to only write out the label for the fields that have values.

For example, if the fields were BLM, USFS, Private, and their values were 10.2, "Null", and 5.5 respectively, I would like the dynamic label to read

**BLM: 10.2 acres

Private: 5.5 acres**

where it skips USFS due to the "Null" value. So far, I have only been able to get this code that I know is incorrect. It returns only the first **true** value and then does not go to the next in the list.

```
Function FindLabel ( [BLM] , [BR] , [Private] , [SITLA] )
  if ( ( [BLM] ) > 0) then  
    FindLabel = "BLM: " + [BLM] + " acres"
  elseif  ( ( [BR] ) > 0) then  
    FindLabel = "BR: " + [BR] + " acres"
  elseif  ( ( [Private] ) > 0) then  
    FindLabel = "Private: " + [Private] + " acres"
  elseif  ( ( [SITLA] ) > 0) then  
    FindLabel = "SITLA: " + [SITLA] + " acres"
  end if 
End Function
```

Attribute table:

[image: Attribute table]

Comment: I saw multiple similar posts and the best advise: **do not use advanced labelling at all**. Simply apply "Define classes of features and label each class differently". This will save your a LOT of time and frustration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Python Parser in the Label Expression window, check on the Advanced box and enter the following:

```py
def FindLabel ( [BLM] , [BR] , [Private] , [SITLA] ):
    xBLM = xBR = xPrivate = xSITLA = ""
    if [BLM]:
        xBLM = "BLM: {} acres \n".format([BLM])
    if [BR]:
        xBR= "BR: {} acres \n".format([BR])
    if [Private]:
        xPrivate= "Private: {} acres \n".format([Private])
    if [SITLA]:
        xSITLA= "SITLA: {} acres \n".format([SITLA])

    return "{}{}{}{}".format(xBLM, xBR, xPrivate, xSITLA)
```

[image]